# A question about permutations of a general adjacency matrix.

Tags: graph-theory, permutations

Two graphs are said *isomorphic* if given the respective adjacency matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$, there exists a permutation matrix $P$ such that

$$PA_1P^T = A_2$$

It is not too clear to me why $P^T$ is used in the definition. Let's consider $A= \begin{pmatrix}0 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 0 & 4\\ 0 & 4 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and the permutation matrix $P=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.

Now it is clear that the product $PA_1$ has the effect of exchanging the rows of $A$, in particular the first row becomes the second, the second becomes the third, and the third becomes the first. Shortly speaking

$$PA = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 4 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & 0\\ 2 & 0 & 4\end{pmatrix}.$$

Now considering $P^T = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and applying $PAP^T$ the result is that the columns change *accordingly* to the rows (i.e. first become second, second becomes third, third becomes one). So if apply again $P$ and not $P^T$ then the columns wouldn't be permuted accordingly to the rows.

Also, is it strictly necessary to permute the columns too? If I have an adjacency matrix and I want to permute only its rows by doing $PA$, then wouldn't I have an isomorphic graph associated to it?

Answer (score 6):

Long story short: If you have a graph and label the vertices $1,2,\ldots,n$ in a certain way, you have one adjacency matrix. If you re-label the vertices in a different order (according to some permutation) then you obtain a different adjacency matrix. The two adjacency matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ are related via $PA_1P^{-1} = A_2$ for some permutation matrix $P$.

Other comments:

- Note that $P^{-1}=P^\top$ because $P$ is an orthogonal matrix. I think using $P^{-1}$ is clearer because this makes it clear that going from $A$ to $PAP^{-1}$ is just a change of basis where you rearrange the components $1,2,\ldots,n$. according to the permutation $P$.
- It is important to "permute both the rows and columns" so that the $i$th row and the $i$th column represent the same vertex in the graph.

Answer (score 2):

To see why this is required note that two graphs are isomorphic if they can be identified up to relabeling. In this case if you permute the rows you can think of it as relabeling the vertices and to ensure that the columns now match the new labels you have to permute them as well. This keeps all the loops on the diagonal.

Answer (score 2):

First: why $P^T$?

Note that a permutation matrix is the matrix associated to a permutation of the basisvectors of a given vector space. This means that any column and any row of the matrix has precisely one 1 and is zero otherwise. Hence, considered as a matrix with real entries, it is an orthogonal matrix and as such its inverse matrix coincides with its transpose.

Second: Why $PAP^T$?

Consider two isomorphic graphs $G_0, G_1$ on $n$ vertices. Let me denote the adjacency matrix of the graph $G_i$ by $A_i$ and identify the vertices of the graph $G_i$ with natural numbers. Suppose we have a graph isomorphism $\phi:G_0 \cong G_1$. It is given by a bijection of the vertices preserving the incidence relation, hence may be identified with a permutation of the natural numbers $\{1,…,n\}$, which itself can be identified with the permutation matrix permuting the basis vectors $e_i$ of $\Bbb R^n$.

Now note that the $j$th component of the vector $A_1 e_i$ indicates wether the vertices $i$ and $j$ are connected in $G_1$. Since $G_0$ and $G_1$ are isomorphic, we should be able to express this adjacency relation in terms of $A_0$. But to do this we have to reverse the isomorphism to use the correct labeling for the vertices of $G_0$, consider the adjacency relation of $G_0$ and then use the isomorphism to turn the labels of vertices back to those of $G_1$. This is precisely what the formula
$$PA_0P^T = A_1$$
does.